# How to add a label to circles in google map angular 2 - sebm-google-map-circle component?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular2-google-maps

I was trying to add text in the middle of circles drawn using **sebm-google-map-circle** angular2 component. It seems its not much easier. If any one know, please let me know. Thanks very much

Comment: For multiple characters : http://jsfiddle.net/LLd4drvx/290/

Comment: For single Character https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels

Comment: Thanks @Chetann . Two thing here 1. I am expecting to do this in angular 2. but these example is not so 2. This shows maker. I need only to show text.

Comment: Got solve second part here which is showing maker. I just set icon: " " and now no more icon showing and only label shows to user. So then the only thing is that how to achieve same thing in angular 2

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue :)

```
    <sebm-google-map-marker 
      [latitude]="lat" 
      [longitude]="lng" 
      [label]="100 USD"
      [iconUrl]="'{}'">
    </sebm-google-map-marker>
```